# Is there Python web application framework for creating desktop-like GUI end-to-end applications?

Tags: python, user-interface

I mean that the user interface and the server logic are like one thing, and no html/js is used.
There is an excellent C++ web toolkit, which does exactly this:

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Is there python equivalent/alternative?

Note: pyjamas does not count - it's great, but client side only.

Thanks!

Comment: Would python bindings for Wt suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, if they are good, complete and maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, Wt is just about the only thing like that. The only thing remotely similar to Wt is ASP.NET, and that is a very long stretch.

Comment: Now this is strange :)
The Wt way looks very promising, I think this is huge part of the future web development. And, it comes from the C++ world. I can't believe there is not pythonic way, yet.

Comment: how about pyjamas + web2py, or pyjamas + django?